# I am using twocolumn svjour3 template to submit a paper. I want to write long equations as a single column. But I get an error message

Tags: math-mode, equations, sv-classes

Here's what I did:
I have the same problem with long equations in the svjour3 document class. I want to display the long equations as a single column. I tried

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
\usepackage{widetext}
\begin{document}

\begin{widetext}
\begin{eqnarray}
%long equation here
\end{eqnarray}
\end{widetext}


\end{document}
```

but I get the error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment widetext undefined.
```

Please help. Thanks!

Added: A link to download svjour3, as requested; https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/svjour3-(springer-journals) .

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Without a link for `widetext` (and presumably `svjour3`) this is not reproducible. I'm calling 'unclear' as what is needed is more info.